# I deleted all of my homework with git reset can I fix this

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I don't know if this is the proper format for this question or if there are any duplicates but I think I just accidentally reset my entire git repository. Is there a command that can reverse this?

I did a git reset on a file I added thinking it would just remove it from that add. I committed it and pushed it. Now my entire git repository is gone except for the code that I just pushed.

```
git reset RadixSort.java
git add *my homework*
git commit -m "BONUS_HW"
git push origin master -f
```

Comment: The very first thing you should do right now is to make a complete copy of the entire folder containing your repository and your working folder. Do nothing else until you've done this. When you start experimenting in order to try to restore your work **experiment on the copy**, leave the original alone, completely alone, except if you need to make another copy of it. Don't touch the original folder until you've concluded and hopefully restored your work.

Comment: In the copy, you can try `git reflog`  to see if it contains the sha of commits you previously had in your repository. You can try checking out those commits with `git checkout SHA` to see if that restores your work. **Again: Do not do this in the original folder**, experiment in a copy.

Comment: Do you remember the exact commands you typed ?

Comment: Also, you should try to think about what commands you used. If you still have them on-screen, or remember them, post them in your question so that we can get a clearer picture of what you did.

Comment: $ git reset RadixSort.java               Then I did a force push

Answer (score 0):

First, make a copy of the entire repository (`cp -R /path/to/your/repo /path/to/backup/dir`).

Now work on the original repo. Assuming you were on the `master` branch, do a `git reflog master`. You should see something like this

```
6ebc064 (HEAD -> master) master@{0}: reset: moving to 6ebc0647a4347d411ea99ded0f9eeb94a5f622bd
ea36a86 master@{1}: commit: Adds README
9065d84 master@{2}: commit: Renames README
1d334db master@{3}: commit: Removed duplicate READMEs
.
.
.
```

The `6ebc064` is where you are right now. `ea36a86` is where your `master` branch was previously. Now, you can reset to that commit using `git reset --hard ea36a86` and it should take the tree to the situation it was in before you did your reset. Once that happens, look through the directory and see if everything is fine. If so, `git push --force` the branch and you're done.

Comment: 1777112 (HEAD -> master, origin/master) master@{0}: commit (initial): BONUS_HW

Comment: thats all that pops up when I use git reflog master can somebody else with developer access to my project delete or remove the files? because I can still see and access them from the activity section of gitlab

Comment: I actually was able to find all of them I think what happened was I force pushed from the parent my original master folder? I really have no clue

Answer (score 0):

First, run

```
$ git log.
```

This will display all the commits that you have made.

1. Find the commit you want.
2. Copy the corresponding SHA number
3. git reset --hard SHA NUMBER
4. push your code

Example:I want to reset my repo to the commit below...

```
  commit 8b665c15673b00ffe833572e1f325452a93f8d15
  Author: Alan <alan@remote.com>
  Date:   Wed Jun 10 11:46:11 2020 -0500

       rename alias on commands.txt
```

Steps

```
$ git reset --hard 8b665c15673b00ffe833572e1f325452a93f8d15
$ git add *
$ git commit -m "revert to 8b665c15673b00ffe833572e1f325452a93f8d15"
$ git push -f origin YOUR WORKING BRANCH
```